# ldap3: Get email address of user

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query

I am using the python ldap3 module. I am able to connect to my company's LDAP service. I would like to query with a username and get the first/last name + email address of this user.

I say:

```
results = conn.search('DC=corp,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com',
                      "(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=" + user_id + "))")
```

When I run this, I get a match:

```
[DN: CN=YYYY\, ZZZZ,OU=Workers,DC=amr,DC=corp,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2020-01-14T20:43:16.146874]
```

So `YYYY` is the last name, `ZZZZ` is the first name. But the email is not present. How do I retrieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Need to specify the attributes to return. For example:

```
results = conn.search('DC=corp,DC=XXXX,DC=com',
                      "(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=" + user_id + "))",
                      ldap3.SUBTREE,
                      attributes=['mail', 'sn', 'givenName'])
```

Comment: use can also use `attributes=['*']` to return all attributes